# Admin page not opening?

Tags: python, django

TypeError at /admin/
'set' object is not reversible
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version: 4.0.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:
'set' object is not reversible
Exception Location: E:\Django Project\Ecom\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 494, in _populate
Python Executable:  E:\Django Project\Ecom\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.6
Python Path:
['E:\Django Project\Ecom',
'C:\Python39\python39.zip',
'C:\Python39\DLLs',
'C:\Python39\lib',
'C:\Python39',
'E:\Django Project\Ecom\venv',
'E:\Django Project\Ecom\venv\lib\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 27 Jan 2022 15:56:51 +0000

Comment: Add your`urls.py` so that we can help you better

Answer (score 0):

In one of your `urls.py` file there may be `{}` in your `urlpatterns` as

```
urlpatterns = {
    path() ........
}
```

Change that `{}` to `[]` as

```
urlpatterns = [
    path() ........
]
```

Comment: Thanku soo much bro

Comment: My pleasure @Nikhil Raj. Welcome to SO. Also if it worked for you then you can accept this answer as `accepted answer` so that it amy helps other in future having same issues.